# Code too slow USACO Bronze 2015 Problem 1 python

Tags: python

I am practicing for USACO and I came across the "Censoring" Problem: http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=526

I solved it pretty quickly and though I got it right. However, it turns out that my the server gives me a time error for test cases 7-15 (it works well for the first 6 test cases).

Here is my code.

```
import sys
sys.stdin = open('censor.in', 'r')
sys.stdout = open('censor.out', 'w')

# Real code begins here
original_string = input()
censor_string = input()
# print(original_string.find(censor_string) + len(censor_string))
while censor_string in original_string:
    original_string = original_string[0:original_string.find(censor_string)] + original_string[original_string.find(censor_string) +
                      len(censor_string): len(original_string)]
print(original_string)
```

Can someone help me fix it? The problem is probably that while loop. Not sure how to fix it though.

Comment: You're looping over the string multiple times -- each time you do `censor_string in original_string` that loops through all of `original_string`, and each call to `find` is another loop, so in all you're looping over the entire `original_string` three times for every occurrence of `censor_string`!.  You should be able to do this in a single pass by iterating over the string and replacing each occurrence as you find it.

Comment: @Samwise Not quite. Have you read the full problem description?

Comment: Keep in mind that you will need to do some backtracking (< 100 characters) since removing an occurrence can create a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fast enough to get accepted. I build the result string one character at a time. Whenever this creates the bad string (at the end of the partial result), I remove it.

```
import sys
sys.stdin = open('censor.in')
sys.stdout = open('censor.out', 'w')

s, t = input(), input()

res = ''
for c in s:
    res += c
    if res.endswith(t):
        res = res[:-len(t)]

print(res)
```